# expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting this error . I have defined all components in index.js and I am using react-router v4. 
Error :Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Match, Link} from 'react-router'

 const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome HOME!</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
 const About = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is About .....</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
 const Topics = ({pathname}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Topics </h2>
            {pathname}
        </div>
    );
};
  const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/topics'>Topics</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <Match  pattern='/' component={Home} />
        <Match  pattern='/about' component={About} />
        <Match  pattern='/topics' component={Topics} />
      </div>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Were you using a alpha/beta release of react-router and then upgraded to the stable v4 release?

Compared to the alpha and beta version of react-router, in the stable v4 release they renamed `Match` to `Route` and they split the package into a core and a dom subpackages (like react does)

Try to change your imports to reflect their stable documentation examples:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

The error you get is because one of your imports is missing and you actually get an undefined value instead of a component class.

Comment: thanks. But, what do i use with react-native-web? @fabio.sussetto

Comment: I have never used react-native-web, but I'd try first with react-router-native and see how it goes with that.